# send commands to a webapp running on tomcat

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat5.5

I'm new with java and tomcat, so, excuse me if it's silly.

I would like to send commands (from the console) to a servlet that is already running on tomcat. The webapp will run the command in the tomcat context and return the appropiate answer.

i.e:

```
$ consoleApp status
running
```

Is it possible?, if yes, how?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make HTTP GET (or POST) requests to your servlet from the command line using tools like `curl` or `wget` and then process the servlet's response. Advantage: If properly set up, you can run those commands also from a remote location.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use several command line tools such as `curl` or `wget` to call your servlet and obtain the response.

Answer (score 0):

and if you want to more than simple, you can make a simple program that communicate with servlet by HTTP Post or GET request. The key is :

> How to communicate with servlet, we can use several http method and
>   any other protocol.